# How many elements are there in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I am studying Ideals and Factor Rings and seem to get stuck on a specific type of questions.
What is the general technique to attack questions like :

**How many elements are there in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I$ where $I$ = $<a+ib>$ ?** (a and b are fixed integers)

Please explain with some examples like: $a+ib = 2+2i$ .

Comment: Let $R=\Bbb{Z}[i]$, show that $|R/z\overline{z} R| = |R/z R||zR/\overline{z}zR|=|R/z R||R/\overline{z}R|=|R/z R|^2$, where $|R/z\overline{z} R| $ is found easily using that $z\overline{z} $ is an integer.

Comment: You said you are studying ideals and factors rings and want a general technique... How general? Any ideal in any ring? There's no such method. Specifically in $\mathbb Z[i]$? Because that's a very particular easy case and the solution for that case won't be a "general technique".

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a very nice geometrical proof with Pick's formula. Let $z = a + bi$ as in your question, with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. We can then consider the lattice

$$ \Lambda = \{z(x + iy) | x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{xz + y (iz) | x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

In this way we can see that it forms a lattice generated by the vectors $z$ and $iz$ (a drawing might help with this but I don't have one with me right now).

The idea now is that $\mathbb{Z}/I$ is going to be the points inside one of the fundamental squares of the lattice (i.e. the one formed by $0,z,iz, (1+i)z$). We also have to count the points on the boundary, but only once because each point will also appear on the opposite side. The exception here is the corners of the square, all of which are the same residue ($0$ because they are all multiples of $z$).

If $i$ are the points of the interior, $b$ the ones in the boundary, we get a total of

$$ i + \frac{b}{2} - 1$$

points, but that is exactly Pick's formula! It now suffices to compute the area and we get that

$$|\mathbb{Z}[i]/I| = a^2 + b^2$$

(the length of each side of the square is $|z|$, so the area is $|z|^2$).

If you know algebraic number theory, the proof is a bit quicker using norms of ideals.